# Need tag abbreviation expansion/synonyms for SEO purposes

Tags: feature-request, tags

As previously discussed in:
[Proposed tag synonyms for [dnd4.0]](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/669/proposed-tag-synonyms)
we have a significant SEO problem stemming from our use of (semi-) standard abbreviations for RPG names in tags.  This is exacerbated by tags not taking special characters and having a 25 character limit.

In the normal SEs, this isn't so much of a problem because [perl], [python], even [windows-server-2008] are short and you can just use them in the tag.

However, common game names in the RPG world are "Dungeons & Dragons Fourth Edition", "Dungeons & Dragons Essentials", "Mutants & Masterminds Second Edition", and similar.  Normally, we'd abbreviate those things like "D&D 4e" but the resulting tags are resulting in poor SEO.

So what do we use?
[dnd4.0] was bad because there was no implicit space between dnd and 4.0.
[dnd-4.0] is somewhat better.  But the dnd isn't quite "D&D".  And what if they are searching on "Dungeons & Dragons?"  Do we tag everything multiple times for SEO reasons?
[dungeons-and-dragons-4e] might be better, but these forms start going over the 25 character tag limit.  [dungeons-and-dragons-essentials] isn't possible. And again, what about searches on "D&D" now? We can NOT have it be the community's job to be retagging every single post with multiple tags to make it more SEO friendly.

Things that could help this a little.
1.  Allow special characters (& especially) in tags.  [d&d-4e] would help.
2.  Let the tag field be a bit bigger, so things like [dungeons-and-dragons-essentials] fit.  40 characters maybe.

The real solution.
More advanced functionality where synonyms, perhaps drawn from the tag wiki, are inserted for SEO purposes.  Let's say we tag with "[dnd4]" for brevity.  If there were a way to configure "hey, that should map to 'D&D 4e' and 'Dungeons & Dragons Fourth Edition' in the tag wikis or synonym screens, and then SE should insert those expanded values into the page (optionally, just for search engines).

Comment: I also put this on the main meta.SE in the hopes someone will care... please go there and vote it up.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72372/need-tag-abbreviation-expansion-synonyms-for-seo-purposes