# Should the new (2nd) edition of The One Ring be tagged separately from the first edition?

Tags: discussion, tags, game-systems, rename-request

The first edition of *The One Ring* was released in 2011 (by Cubicle 7). However, [Free League Publishing recently released a new (2nd) edition of the game](https://freeleaguepublishing.com/en/games/the-one-ring/):

> Now in its second edition, The One Ring™ comes with updated and
> revised rules, a new visual style, and a focus on the land of Eriador
> — the lone-lands west of the Misty Mountains.

Currently, there is only one tag for the *The One Ring* role-playing game: [the-one-ring](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-one-ring).

However, at least one question on the site (which currently uses the same tag) is specifically about the second edition of the game: [The One Ring 2nd Edition says players should choose "their favoured selection of armour" as starting equipment, what does it mean by this?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/195527/the-one-ring-2nd-edition-says-players-should-choose-their-favoured-selection-of)

**Should the *The One Ring* 2e have a separate tag from *TOR* 1e?**

Additionally, if a separate [the-one-ring-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-one-ring-2e) tag is created: **Should the existing [the-one-ring](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-one-ring) tag be renamed to [the-one-ring-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-one-ring-1e) accordingly?**

Comment: I own the first edition, but have not looked at the 2nd edition and can't comment personally on how much the rule revision changes things though I lean towards creating separate edition tags and renaming the original tag personally.

Comment: I edited your post to add some additional details (and a link to a question on the site that's specifically about 2e).

Answer (score 5):

### Yes; we did this with AD&D 1e and AD&D 2e a few years back.

While I'm not familiar enough with that game to get into details, it would be consistent with how we tag Traveller, AD&D, WoD, etc.

Comment: Some games don't have much of a significant difference between their individual editions though, such that tagging editions differently isn't necessarily helpful. For example, [see this meta question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/should-these-gurps-questions-have-an-edition-specific-system-tag) where I ask about GURPS question having their editions distinguished. It's important we make the decision that works for this game based on whether this game needs this, or needs us to _not_ do this.

Comment: The relevant discussion for AD&D: [Should we rename the \[adnd\] tag to \[adnd-1e\]?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9298/33569)