# Should the dnd3e tag cover all third edition, or just 3.0?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are separate tags for [dnd-3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-3e) and [dnd-3.5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5). Does the dnd-3e tag refer to all of D&D third edition (including 3.5) or only pre-3.5 D&D (also called 3.0)?

Comment: If D&D3e refers to 3.0 then we should just rename it to D&D3.0e.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there is a separate tag for D&D 3.5 it would only include questions that pertain to pre 3.5 material. Questions for 3.5 material should be filed with the 3.5 tag.

Answer (score 3):

The current consensus (always up for revisiting!) was developed here: [Proposed tag synonyms for [dnd4.0]](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/669/proposed-tag-synonyms-for-dnd4-0/672#672) .

So [dnd-3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-3e) is currently intended to be for just 3e-not-including-3.5e, and [dnd-3.5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5) is intended for just D&D 3.5. I've clarified [the tag wiki for [dnd-3e]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/dnd-3e/info) to say so.

However, you might have noticed that very few questions are actually 3.0-specific. The idea at the time was that we should preclude the possibility that people would want to ask 3.0-specific questions. In practice, that hasn't really been a strong need yet. The logic still holds: people might want to ask 3.0-specific questions… but at some point, that allowance just becomes naïve. Having an umbrella tag might be useful. So, revisiting these assumptions is certainly possible.

One possible reorganisation would be to have this:

- [dnd-3.x](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-3.x) (for all of 3.x, maybe with [dnd-3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-3e) as a synonym)

  - [dnd-3.0](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-3.0) (for questions specific to 3.0)
  - [dnd-3.5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5) (for questions specific to 3.5)

In practical terms, retagging a pile of questions of a sudden can be disruptive, so there's also that to weigh when considering changing things up.

Comment: I see zero value in adding a 3.x tag...

Comment: @mxyzplk The value I can see is eliminating a lot of double-tagging on 3.x questions. Whether that's *much* more than zero, I'm less sure of.

Comment: We just wasted more time talking about it than all double-tagging in the history of the site combined. Flee!